# Bluetooth print fails half way in qt android application

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, qt5.4

I am connecting to a bluetooth printer from an android device and printing. If the data is too big  it only prints half of it. :( I am not sure why is it so...

The below are the logs

```
D/BluetoothUtils(13396): isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
W/BluetoothAdapter(13396): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
D/BluetoothSocket(13396): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[86]}
E/File    (13396): fail readDirectory() errno=2
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void SyncObjAPI::postBillDetails() Exits
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void SyncObjAPI::parseBillPostNwResponse(QNetworkReply*) Invoked
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void SyncObjAPI::parseBillPostNwResponse(QNetworkReply*) network get error happened "Protocol "" is unknown"
W/System.err(13396): java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
W/System.err(13396):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:550)
W/System.err(13396):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:527)
W/System.err(13396):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:357)
W/System.err(13396):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
W/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android: Falling back to workaround.
W/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android: Cannot determine RFCOMM service channel.
W/BluetoothAdapter(13396): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
D/BluetoothSocket(13396): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[88]}
W/System.err(13396): java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
W/System.err(13396):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:550)
W/System.err(13396):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:527)
W/System.err(13396):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:357)
W/System.err(13396):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
W/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android: Socket connect via workaround failed.
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void BluetoothPrint::handleErrorOccurance(QBluetoothSocket::SocketError) Invoked QBluetoothSocket::ServiceNotFoundError
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): Connection to service failed
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void ErrorDialog::setTitle(QString) Invoked "ERROR IN BLUETOOTH PRINT"
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void ErrorDialog::setTitle(QString) Exits
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void ErrorDialog::setMessage(QString) Invoked "Connection to service failed"
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void ErrorDialog::setIcon(QIcon) Invoked
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void BluetoothPrint::handleErrorOccurance(QBluetoothSocket::SocketError) Exit
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void BluetoothPrint::connectedDev() Invoked
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): void BluetoothPrint::connectedDev() to send data
W/System.err(13396): java.io.IOException: socket closed
W/System.err(13396):    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:92)
W/System.err(13396):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:472)
W/System.err(13396):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
W/System.err(13396):    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
W/System.err(13396):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bluetooth.QtBluetoothInputStreamThread.run(QtBluetoothInputStreamThread.java:77)
D/AcePOS  (13396): (null):0 ((null)): disconnected() Invoked
```

I use **Qt Creator 3.3.1 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.4.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)** and **Android 4.4.2**

I saw a bug reported [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40172) , even though it says fixed.. i get this error :(

Any fix is there to do this?

// bluetoothprint.cpp

```
#include "bluetoothprint.h"
#include "commondefenitions.h"
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QTimer>
BluetoothPrint::BluetoothPrint(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent), m_pBtSocket(NULL)
{
    m_pErrorDlg = new ErrorDialog();

    m_pBtSocket = new QBluetoothSocket(QBluetoothServiceInfo::RfcommProtocol);
    mCommand    = false;

    connect(m_pBtSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connectedDev()));
    connect(m_pBtSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnectedDev()));
    connect(m_pBtSocket, SIGNAL(error(QBluetoothSocket::SocketError)),this,
                     SLOT(handleErrorOccurance(QBluetoothSocket::SocketError)));

}

void BluetoothPrint::write(QByteArray data, QString ipAddress, bool logo)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    if (NULL == m_pBtSocket)
    {
        return;
    }

    mCommand = false;
    mLogo = logo;
    m_data = data;
    m_ipAddress = ipAddress;

    static const QLatin1String serviceUuid("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Create socket";

    if(NULL != ipAddress)
    {
        QBluetoothAddress address = QBluetoothAddress(ipAddress);
        m_pBtSocket->connectToService(address,QBluetoothUuid(serviceUuid),QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "ConnectToService done";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "IP Address is empty";
    }

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exit";
}

void BluetoothPrint::writeCommand(QByteArray data, QString ipAddress)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";
    mCommand = true;
    m_cashDrawerData = data;
    m_ipAddress = ipAddress;

    static const QLatin1String serviceUuid("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Create socket";

    if(NULL != ipAddress)
    {
        QBluetoothAddress address = QBluetoothAddress(ipAddress);
        m_pBtSocket->connectToService(address,QBluetoothUuid(serviceUuid),QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "ConnectToService done";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "IP Address is empty";
    }

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exit";
}

void BluetoothPrint::printLogo()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    QByteArray align;
    align[0] = 27;
    align[1] = 97;
    align[2] = 1;

    QByteArray res;
    res[0] = 28;
    res[1] = 112;
    res[2] = 1;
    res[3] = 0;

    m_pBtSocket->write(align);
    m_pBtSocket->write(res);

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exit";
}

void BluetoothPrint::connectedDev()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    if (mCommand)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "to send command";
        m_pBtSocket->write(m_cashDrawerData);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "to send data";

        if (mLogo)
        {
            printLogo();
        }

        m_pBtSocket->write(m_data);
        m_pBtSocket->write("\n\n\n\n\n\r");
        m_pBtSocket->write(PARTIAL_PAPER_CUT);
    }

    m_pBtSocket->disconnectFromService();
}

void BluetoothPrint::disconnectedDev()
{
    qDebug("disconnected() Invoked");
    qDebug(qPrintable("Disconnected from Bluetooth Printer"));
}

void BluetoothPrint::handleErrorOccurance(QBluetoothSocket::SocketError error)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked" << error;

    qDebug(qPrintable(m_pBtSocket->errorString()));
    m_pErrorDlg->setTitle("ERROR IN BLUETOOTH PRINT");
    m_pErrorDlg->setMessage(m_pBtSocket->errorString());
    m_pErrorDlg->setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/images/salesscreen/icons/error.png"));
    m_pErrorDlg->show();

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exit";
}

BluetoothPrint::~BluetoothPrint()
{
    if (NULL != m_pBtSocket)
    {
        delete m_pBtSocket;
        m_pBtSocket = NULL;
    }
}
```

and calls the write function with text...

Comment: Can you show the relevant code that generates this error?